# Defined Variable's Existence not Acknowledged by Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am simply attempting to define a variable in Python. I am using Spyder and in the variable explorer, the defined variable "V0Z" does not show up at all. There is no error message that appears and I double checked my math by plugging in the definition into Wolfram Alpha and it gives me a real number (1.5E+7). Why is Python refusing to acknowledge it?

Code:

```
import numpy as np

MirrorAngle = 30
V0X = 1E7
MirrorAngleRad = MirrorAngle*(np.pi/180)
V0Z = (np.abs(V0X)/np.abs(np.sin(MirrorAngleRad)))*(1 - np.sin(MirrorAngleRad)**2)
```

Screenshot of what I see: [image]

Comment: do you have problem to do `print(V0Z)` ? Maybe problem has Spyder, not Python.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that *Spyder*, more specifically the variable explorer, doesn't acknowledge the variable? You say you are not getting any Python errors, correct?

Comment: Python acknowledges this just fine; it seems to be Spyder that is your problem.  Can you post a series of screen shots where you expect to see the variable?

Comment: You are all correct I believe. It may be a problem with Spyder. I also restarted Spyder to see if that fixed it and it did not.

Comment: Perhaps it may have something to do with the fact that the number is very large and it does not like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spyder's Variable Explorer doesn't show all-uppercase variables by default. You can change this in the hamburger menu on the pane, just uncheck the box to hide those variables:

[image: screenshot of menu]

The likely reason all-caps variables are hidden by default is that many style guides recommend all-caps for constants, so they'll never change during the lifetime of a program. That would make monitoring them in the variable explorer pretty pointless.

Comment: Thank you this worked. Makes no sense why that is a default setting!

Comment: @Tom: Well, like I mention at the end of the answer, it's probably because `ALL_CAPS` names are usually for constants and you don't really need to monitor them. Many style guides might suggest you rename `V0Z` to `v0z` or similar, though I wouldn't have a problem with it myself. It's a bit unusual since it's got two one-letter parts separated by a number, rather than being a proper word. But I'm not shocked that Spyder can't tell the difference between it and a more conventional constant's name.